# VB plus color in grids

Tags: vb6, grid

Is there a way to put color in rows(flexgrids)? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim i as Integer
With myFlexGrid
  .Row = rowToChange
  For i = 0 to .Cols - 1
    .Col = i
    .CellBackColor = vbColorValue
  Next i
End With
```

This will change the whole row color for whichever row you set with myFlexGrid.Row. This does not work with rows you designate as fixed.